# Expected to find ')' in Positioned in flutter

Tags: flutter

how do i fix this

> [Text]([https://stackoverflow.com/fluttererror.png[Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/fluttererror.png%5BExpected) to find ')'][1])

```
),Positioned(
          top: 504,
          left: 320,
          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ellipse2.svg', semanticsLabel: 'ellipse2'
          );//line 59 error
),Positioned(
           top: 782,
           left: -77,
           child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ellipse3.svg',semanticsLabel: 'ellipse3'
      );//line 64 error
```

what i've tried is adding ')' to line 59 and 64, putting const on the widget still the same error

Comment: Show ALL the relevant section please, this is not supposed to be a guessing game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems simply that you put the semicolon at the end of your SvgPicture, you should replace those with a comma!

```
),Positioned(
          top: 504,
          left: 320,
          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ellipse2.svg', semanticsLabel: 'ellipse2'
          ), //Comma goes here
),Positioned(
           top: 782,
           left: -77,
           child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ellipse3.svg',semanticsLabel: 'ellipse3'
      ), //Comma goes here
```

Comment: thanks it works!, i must pretty burnout to not thought of that

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
),Positioned(
          top: 504,
          left: 320,
          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ellipse2.svg', semanticsLabel: 'ellipse2'
          );
),Positioned(
           top: 782,
           left: -77,
           child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ellipse3.svg',semanticsLabel: 'ellipse3'
      );
```

to

```
),Positioned(
          top: 504,
          left: 320,
          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ellipse2.svg', semanticsLabel: 'ellipse2'
          ),
),Positioned(
           top: 782,
           left: -77,
           child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ellipse3.svg',semanticsLabel: 'ellipse3'
      ),
```